# How to write Pytest for AWS Athena service

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pytest, amazon-athena

I am writing pytest for my lambda which is using AThena, created pytest.fixture using below code:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def moto_boto_athena():
    @mock_athena
    def boto_resource_athena():
        res = boto3.client('athena')
        return res
    return boto_resource_athena
```

My Lambda is having below code:

```
response = get_athena_client().start_query_execution(
        QueryString=query_string,
        QueryExecutionContext={
            'Database': athena_database
        },
        ResultConfiguration={
            'OutputLocation': athena_output_bucket,
        }
    )

    query_status = None
    #Check the status of QueryExecution
    while query_status == 'QUEUED' or query_status == 'RUNNING' or query_status is None:
        query_status = get_athena_client(). \
            get_query_execution(QueryExecutionId=response['QueryExecutionId'])['QueryExecution']['Status']['State']
        if query_status == 'FAILED' or query_status == 'CANCELLED':
            raise Exception
```

But as soon as I start my test execution, getting below exception:

```
raise NotImplementedError(
>           "The {0} action has not been implemented".format(action)
        )
E       NotImplementedError: The start_query_execution action has not been implemented

..\..\..\..\..\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\moto\core\responses.py:393: NotImplementedError
```

Please guide.

Comment: Looks like you have mocked the athena client, but your mock client doesn't has get_query_execution function implemented i.e to say abstract.

Comment: @HarshBafna How to implement get_query_execution function then?

Comment: you'll have to create that method yourself. you will need to tack on to this [class](https://github.com/spulec/moto/blob/master/moto/athena/models.py)